# How to use a function to open a csv and convert it to a dictionary?

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary

I am having trouble calling the function I made to open a CSV file. I am getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'keys'.

In my `for` loop it won't load the `load_dict` I created from the function. Any help is appreciated! Please go easy, I am a beginner.

```
import csv

invest_dict = 'DOW_Stock_short.csv'

def load_dict():
    with open(invest_dict , 'r') as invest_obj:
        invest_reader = csv.reader(invest_obj)
        result = {}
        for row in invest_reader:
            if invest_reader.line_num !=1:
                key = row[0]
                result[key] = float(row[1])
        return(result)

print("The purpose of this project is to provide Stock Analysis by reading \n the data from a csv file and performing analysis on this data.")

def Greeting():
    print(".........Welcome.............")

def Conversions(investment_amount):

    investment_amount = float(investment_amount)

    Euro = float(round(investment_amount / 1.113195,2) )
    Pound = float(round(investment_amount / 1.262304,2) )
    Rupee = float(round(investment_amount / 0.014316,2) )

    print("The amount you invest in euro is:  {:.2f}" .format(Euro) )
    print("The amount you invest in pounds is:  {:.2f}" .format(Pound) ) 
    print("The amount you invested in Rupees is:  {:.2f}" .format(Rupee) )


def minimum_stock():
    key_min = min(load_dict.keys(), key = (lambda k: load_dict[k]))
    print("The lowest stock you can buy is: ",load_dict[key_min])


def maximum_stock():
    key_max = max(load_dict.key(), key = (lambda k: load_dict[k]))
    print("The highest stock you may purchase is: ",load_dict[key_max])


def invest_range(investment_amount):
    new_list = []
    new_list = [i for i in load_dict if i >=50 and i <=600]
    return(sorted(new_list))

answer = 'yes'

while answer:

print(Greeting())

try:
    investment_amount = float(input("Please enter the amount you want to invest:$ "))
    print("Thank you for investing:$ {:,.2f}".format(investment_amount))
except:
    print("Please enter a valid amount...")
    continue 

print(Conversions(investment_amount))


for i in load_dict():
    i = investment_amount
    if i <25:
        print("Not enough funds to purchase stock")
        break
    elif i>25 and i <250:
        print(minimum_stock())
        break
    elif i >= 250 and i <= 1000:
        print(maximum_stock())
        break

print("This is the range of stocks you may purchase: ", invest_range(investment_amount))

answer = input("Would you like to complete another conversion? yes/no " )
if answer == 'no':
    print("Thank you for investing.")
    break
```

I want the output to display the contents of the dictionary depending on what the user inputs. error message:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: Is your code after `while` indented properly?

Comment: `load_dict()` has no input parameters, how should it know what to load? Try to define it as `def load_dict(invest_dict):`

Comment: Yes, I added the input parameters and defined it as load_dict(invest_dict): and now I figured it out. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief: instead of appying the `.keys()` to the result of the function you are applying it to the function itself, and that is what the error says. Try to call the function instead:

```
# Wrong:
# load_dict.keys()

load_dict().keys()
```

This would (probably) solve your problem but from what I can see from the rest of your code, you use the function multiple times like you should use the result of it. So it's better to cache the result before using it:

```
load_dict = load_dict()

load_dict.keys()
```

Comment: I tried adding it and got this :'function' object is not subscriptable ???

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I added the load_dict(invest_dict) and got it to work for my functions. Thank you very much for your time and help! It was much appreciated!